# LINQ: How to sort the items of a recursive tree structure?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this entity model:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } = new List<ProductCategory>();
}
```

How can I write a LINQ query that sorts a recursive tree structure of categories correctly? This is what I have now:

```
var categories = _context.ProductCategories
                        .Include(e => e.Children).ToList().OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder)
                        .Where(e => e.ParentId == null)
                        .OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder);
```

The root categories (with `ParentId == null` are correctly sorted, but the children are not.

Comment: What do you mean by recursive? That each ProductCategory has a list of child categories?

Comment: A dupe from 2013, I don't think anything has changed. You cannot filter or sort a Details list.

Comment: @GilGrossman Yes. And each child can have children too. Hence the `ParentId`-field in the model.